# Não estou conseguindo chamar um arquivo jquery no html

Tags: html, jquery, css

Bom estou com um problema para chamar uma script o navbar aparece tudo certinho como na img:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a script não carrega não sei oq acontece já tentei mudar a ordem e tudo e não vai ..

Codigo :

```css
#body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;

}/* Style for our header texts
 * --------------------------------------- */
 h1{
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: arial,helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }

 /* Centered texts in each section
 * --------------------------------------- */
 .section{
  text-align:center;
 }


 /* Backgrounds will cover all the section
 * --------------------------------------- */
 #section0,
 #section1,
 #section2,
 #section3{
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 /* Defining each sectino background and styles
 * --------------------------------------- */
 #section0{
  background-image: url(imgs/fundo1.jpg);
 }
 #section0 h1{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
 }
 #section1{
   background-image: url(imgs/fundo4.jpg);
  }
  #section1 h1{
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   position: relative;
  }
 #section2{
  background-image: url(imgs/fundo2.png);
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
 }
 #section3{
  background-image: url(imgs/fundo4.jpg);
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
 }
 #section3 h1{
  color: #000;
 }



.cnt
{
 height: 635px;
 background-color: orangered;
}

 /* Bottom menu
 * --------------------------------------- */
 #infoMenu li a {
  color: #fff;
 }

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: helvetica;
}



header{
 z-index: 333;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: transparent;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
}

nav{
 display: table;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 height: 40px;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s;
}

ul{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}

ul li{
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 2px;
}

ul a{
 color: #F3F3F3;
 text-decoration: none;
}

img#logo{
 
 float:left;
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;

 -webkit-transition: width .5s, height .5s, margin-right .5s, margin-top .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Fixed fullscreen backgrounds - fullPage.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />
 


 <!--[if IE]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var console = { log: function() {} };
  </script>
 <![endif]-->


 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<header class="header">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Inicio</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Videos</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Im&aacute;genes</li></a>
   </ul>
    
    <img id='logo' src='pictures/logo.png'>

   <ul>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Youtube</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Nosotros</li></a>
    <a href='http://www.keyquotes.es'><li>Contacto</li></a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="cnt">
 fafq
 </section>

<div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section " id="section0"><h1>fullPage.js</h1></div>
 <div class="section " id="section1"><h1>fullPdsadass</h1></div>
 <div class="section" id="section2"><h1>Lovely images <br />for a lovely page</h1></div>
 <div class="section" id="section3"><h1>One Image = One thousand words</h1></div>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/examples.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,

    //to avoid problems with css3 transforms and fixed elements in Chrome, as detailed here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/208
    css3:false
   });
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Já tentei adiconar em baixo da script da one page, mas não funciona e buga a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,

            //to avoid problems with css3 transforms and fixed elements in Chrome, as detailed here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/208
            css3:false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alguém podeira me ajudar a solucionar isso?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo. Veja se dá algum erro no console do navegador...

Comment: Não deu está normal..

Comment: Creio q tenha algum problema com a ordem do script.

Comment: Você está chamando 2 jquerys, provavelmente é isso. Chame apenas um só. E o seu example.js deve ser o último deles, caso seja nesse script que você tenha configurado suas funções...

Comment: Ah pow isso ai foi só no snippet no meu localhost está só um e não ta indo. E quando eu boto no último buga toda a script da one page..

Comment: pq vc chama duas versões diferentes de jquery?, este example.js possivelmente deveria ser o ultimo a ser chamado, não?

Comment: Tipo a última script jquery q está na page é da one page, e então eu não sei se eu boto a script do navbar por último ou não, sim eu chamo só a atual?

Comment: Então arrume seu código exatamente como está no seu localhost. E não precisa de usar o snippet, a não ser que você queira simular a situação.

Comment: é pq eu estou usnado 2 scripts e uma estava usando  o 2.1

Comment: A outra 1 .8, mas eu chamo só a 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos organizar em partes, scripts e afins dentro da head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/examples.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
```

agora vamos corrigir o seu erro, removendo multiplos jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/examples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

caso precise usar todos esses jquery use esse script para remover o conflito

```
<script>var $oldjQuery = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Comment: Opa mano eu coloco tudo acima da script do one page?

Comment: <head> nessa parte </head>

Comment: se voce colocar no jsfindle eu corrigo para vc

Comment: opa blz vou colocar aqui agora.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k41t9n52/ Eu botei no jfiddle, mas não mostrou o problema no snippet do stack tem como ver oq aconteceu.

Comment: conseguiu bro? ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k41t9n52/2/ desse jeito, nao precisa das outras jquery

Comment: Vlw mano eu tava ficando  confuso já, ele sem está no html do website funcionava de boa, mas agr no html n ..

Comment: Mano eu vou fazer uma outra pergunta relacionada a mudar a cor do menu <li> na script você poderia me ajudar? Te mando o link aq.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71177/discussion-between-hudsonph-and-felipe).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266890/algu%C3%A9m-poderia-me-ajudar-com-essa-script mano se tiver como ajudar lá .