# Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa script?

Tags: jquery

**Bom a script :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#banner").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"});

    var flag = false;
    var scroll;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scroll > 200){
            if(!flag){
                $("#logo").css({"margin-top": "-5px", "width": "50px","height":"50px"});
                $("nav").css({"color": "#fff"});
                $("ul").css({"color": "#000"});
                flag = true;
            }
        }else{
            if(flag){
                $("#logo").css({ "width": "80px","height":"80px"});
                $("ul").css({"color": "#000"});
                $("header").css({"background-color": "#fff"});
                flag = false;
            }
        }


    });

});
```

Parte html do nav:

```
<header class="header">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Youtube</li></a>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Nosotros</li></a>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Contacto</li></a>
            </ul>

                <img id="logo" src="pictures/logo.png">

            <ul>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Youtube</li></a>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Nosotros</li></a>
                <a href="http://www.keyquotes.es"><li>Contacto</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>

</header>
```

**Eu queria entender oq está faltando ou onde estou errando, a minha intenção com essa script é que quando a page esteja no top o ul fique black img:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**e quando for rolando o scroll ela fique white como na img:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> E então eu adicionei isso na script: $("ul").css({"color": "#000"}); e
>   $("ul").css({"color": "#fff"}); , e não foi qual seria melhor opção?

Comment: pode explicar o que voce quer

Comment: Eu deixei bem explicado, mas tipo como vc viu na img o <ul><li> está preto, mas eu queria adiconar na script ao rolar a barra o <ul><li> mudasse a color para white .

Comment: pode postar o codigo completo desde o html

Comment: mas precisa do html, é só na script não?

Comment: vou editar aqui então .

Comment: @MarceloBatista pronto bro .

Comment: Coloca o código inteiro o HTML todo, inclusive com CSS e JS, vai ficar mais fácil de te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos la, vc nao precisa desse `flag` e o correto para mudar a cor é `$("nav ul a")`

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 200){
            $("#logo").css({"margin-top": "-5px", "width": "50px","height":"50px"});
            $("nav ul a").css({"color": "blue"});                
            $("header").css({"background-color": "#fff"});
    }else{
            $("#logo").css({ "width": "80px","height":"80px"});
            $("nav ul a").css({"color": "#fff"});
            $("header").css({"background-color": "#000"});

    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k41t9n52/3/

Comment: então eu só errei a tag no caso? mt obrigado man!.

Comment: Bro pode me tirar mais uma duvida? Tem como fazer uma page one page e outra page one page dentro dessa pagina? tipo isso aqui: https://elojobbrasil.com.br/#loja vc teria algo soobre para dar uma estudada?